Excel formula to check given date is in which date range?
Can anyone be able to simplify this excel formula, do note its working doing exactly what it is intended to do.
=IF(D2>=DATEVALUE("1/7/2024"), IF(D2<=DATEVALUE("6/7/2024"),VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE), IF(D2>=DATEVALUE("7/7/2024"), IF(D2<=DATEVALUE("14/7/2024"),VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.75,IF(D2>=DATEVALUE("15/07/2024"), IF(D2<=DATEVALUE("21/07/2024"),VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.5,IF(D2>=DATEVALUE("22/7/2024"), IF(D2<=DATEVALUE("31/7/2024"),VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.25,"f"),"F")),"F")),"F")),VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE))
But now I have issue of explaining this to someone who is new to process. So was trying to make is simple by adding function date between which failed also its not inbuilt for me.

You can use a table and non-exact match for a lookup to create better 'buckets' then putting them into a formula explicitly where you would presumably have to keep updating or extending the formula until you couldn't

To simplify this formula I would use a lookup utilizing it's non-exact matching and a table. This allows the formula to scale effortlessly as the dates inevitably need to be updated instead of the formula.
Create a table with all the dates you need and second column for the other data point (judging from the formula it seems like you take something for that date and multiply it against a factor that you could put in this table.
The basic concept is below. To apply it to what you're doing put those factors into the table and simply do the lookup you're doing to pull the value then multiply it against the factor you're pulling based on the date. I've done this for effective prices against FOREX, and conceptually very similar to what I see here.


Its a good practice to format formulas using line breaks to help future maintainers (alt+enter is your friend).
IF(
  D2>=DATEVALUE("1/7/2024"),
  IF(
     D2<=DATEVALUE("6/7/2024"),
     VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE),
     IF(
       D2>=DATEVALUE("7/7/2024"),
       IF(
         D2<=DATEVALUE("14/7/2024"),
         VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.75,
         IF(
           D2>=DATEVALUE("15/07/2024"),
           IF(
             D2<=DATEVALUE("21/07/2024"),
             VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.5,
             IF(
               D2>=DATEVALUE("22/7/2024"),
               IF(
                 D2<=DATEVALUE("31/7/2024"),
                 VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)*0.25,
                 "f"
               ),
               "F"
             )
           ),
           "F"
         )
       ),
       "F"
     )
  ),
  VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE)
)

So breaking down your formula one can:

the IF ladder can be replaced by a IFS function
Date range checks be put inside AND statements like: AND(D2>=DATEVALUE("1/7/2024"), D2<=DATEVALUE("6/7/2024")
The Comum VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE) can be put in a variable within a LET function

Something like this:
LET(
  Look, VLOOKUP(C2,Calendar!$A$13:$E$20,5,FALSE),
  IFS(
     D2<DATEVALUE("1/7/2024"), Look,
     AND(D2>=DATEVALUE("1/7/2024"), D2<=DATEVALUE("6/7/2024")), Look,
     AND(D2>=D2>=DATEVALUE("7/7/2024"), D2<=DATEVALUE("14/7/2024")), Look * 0.75, 
     AND(D2>=D2>=DATEVALUE("15/07/2024"), D2<=DATEVALUE("21/07/2024")), Look * 0.5,
     AND(D2>=D2>=DATEVALUE("22/7/2024"), D2<=DATEVALUE("31/7/2024")), Look * 0.25,
     TRUE, "F"
  )
) 

EDIT1: this was just a helper guide if you can't change the way data if available to you or you really what (for some other reason) to put everything inside a formula)
EDIT2: as Mark pointed out there are better ways to achieve the same result.
